# How to group same table differently in outer query and subquery

Tags: mysql

Table looks like this:

```
id | number       | provider| datetime | keyword|country| 
1  | 1            | Mobitel |2012-11-05|    JAM |    RS |       
2  | 2            | Telekom |2013-04-25|   ASTRO|    RS |           
3  | 1            | Si.Mobil|2013-04-27|  DOMACE|    BA |             
4  | 4            | Telenor |2013-04-21|    BIP |    HR |      
5  | 7            | VIP     |2013-04-18|    WIN |    CZ |       
6  | 13           | VIP     |2014-05-21|  DOMACE|    RS |       
7  | 5            | VIP     |2014-06-04|    WIN |    HU |
```

I need to sum all numbers grouped by keyword and country and to sum all numbers again grouped by keyword, country and provider all in one query.

Here is how I tried to do it:

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(number),country, keyword  
        FROM daily_subscriptions 
        WHERE datetime >= '2016-02-01  23:59:59'  
        GROUP BY country, keyword ) 
    num_of_all_subs, 
    SUM(number) as num_of_subs,
    country, 
    keyword, 
    provider  
FROM daily_subscriptions  
WHERE datetime >= '2016-02-01  23:59:59'  
GROUP BY country, keyword, provider
```

But this query throws an error:

> #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Here is what I expect to get:

```
id | num_of_all_subs|num_of_subs | provider| datetime | keyword|country| 
1  | 19             | 4          | Mobitel |2012-11-05|    JAM |    RS |       
2  | 12             | 5          |Telekom  |2013-04-25|   ASTRO|    RS |        
3  | 18             | 1          |Si.Mobil |2013-04-27|  DOMACE|    BA |          
4  | 42             | 21         |Telenor  |2013-04-21|    BIP |    HR |      
5  | 76             | 23         |VIP      |2013-04-18|    WIN |    CZ |       
6  | 13             | 3          |VIP      |2014-05-21|  DOMACE|    RS |       
7  | 53             | 11         |VIP      |2014-06-04|    WIN |    HU |
```

Field `num_of_all_subs` meaning that sum of all numbers for lets say JAM(keyword) and RS(country) is 19 , but per Mobitel(provider) is `num_of_subs` 4 from all 19, since there are other providers for that country and keyword(even though they are not displayed in table schema).

Please help me to extract this data, since I'm stuck.

Comment: choose between sql-server or mysql, but not both

Comment: good, now show your expected output, it's not clear to me if you want total and subtotal on the same row, or if you want them in separate rows

Comment: @ThomasG is it clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subquery for `num_of_all_subs` (which is a single number) must only return one column and, next problem, one row. Also, this subquery will be evaluated before you group, while you actually want to first group and get the columns `num_of_subs`, `country`, `keyword` and `provider`, and, afterwards, add another column `num_of_all_subs` to that first resultset.

You can do this exactly as just described: first get the grouped subquery (here called `details`), then use a dependent subquery to get, for each row in that subquery, the value for `num_of_all_subs` by looking at the table (again) and sum over all rows that have the same `provider` and `country`:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT SUM(number)
     FROM daily_subscriptions ds
     WHERE datetime >= '2016-02-01  23:59:59'  
      and ds.country = details.country 
      and ds.keyword = details.keyword
    ) as num_of_all_subs,
    details.*
from
(select 
    SUM(number) as num_of_subs,
    country, 
    keyword, 
    provider  
 FROM daily_subscriptions  
 WHERE datetime >= '2016-02-01  23:59:59'  
 GROUP BY country, keyword, provider
) as details;
```

An alternative would be to do calculate both groups seperately, one including `provider` (`details`), and one without (`all_subs`). One will contain `num_of_subs`, one will contain `num_of_all_subs`. The you can combine (`join`) these two queries when they have the same `country` and `keyword`:

```
SELECT 
    all_subs.num_of_all_subs,
    details.*
from
(select 
    SUM(number) as num_of_subs,
    country, 
    keyword, 
    provider  
 FROM daily_subscriptions  
 WHERE datetime >= '2016-02-01  23:59:59'  
 GROUP BY country, keyword, provider
) as details
left join 
(SELECT 
    SUM(number) as num_of_all_subs,
    country, 
    keyword
 FROM daily_subscriptions
 WHERE datetime >= '2016-02-01  23:59:59'  
 GROUP BY country, keyword
) as all_subs
on all_subs.keyword = details.keyword and all_subs.country = details.country;
```

In your case, you can use a `join` instead of a `left join`, because every row in the first subquery will have a row in the second subquery, although it's usually the safer way do keep it.

While in theory, MySQL could execute these queries identically (and for less complicated queries, it will actually optimize and treat, whenever possible and useful, dependent subqueries like joins), in current MySQL versions this will most likely not be the case and the 2nd option is probably faster. Anyway, for both versions, a composite index on `(country, keyword, provider)` will do wonders.